# selecting from multiple tables where results occur less than X amount on another table

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure the best way to ask this question so thank you in advance for dealing with my confusion.

here is the query i came up with:

```
SELECT a.id FROM assets a, courseAssets ca, courses c, assetTags at WHERE c.courseUser = {$userId} AND c.id = ca.courseID and ca.assetID = a.id AND count(at.assetID = a.id) <5
```

This works all the way up to the 3rd "and". after that point I'm trying to take the results and find them in assetTags and only return the ids that occur less than 5 times.

hope this makes sense, I can see it i my mind just not sure how to get all the way there. I'm sure there is a UNION, Join or something.

Comment: Do you really need to join 4 tables? Isn't `assets` and `assetTags` enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix aggregate functions like `count` with "normal" column selects. 
To avoid that use a `group by` and put the aggregate condition in the `having` clause.

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM assets a
inner join courseAssets ca on ca.assetID = a.id
inner join courses c on c.id = ca.courseID
inner join assetTags at on at.assetID = a.id
group by a.id
having count(distinct at.assetID) < 5
```

BTW it is best practice to get used to the join syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a couple questions.1st: This query only counts if there is at least 1 record. is there a way to include no record(or 0) into the results. 2nd: Do you have a good resource for understanding joins? I've been working with them for a bit now, but i still struggle to understand when to use them and in what order.

Comment: 1. replace `inner join` with `left outer join`. 2. [See this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a GROUP BY clause if you want to do a count or summation properly.

This is probably close to what you're after:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
SELECT a.id, count(ast.assetID) AS counter
FROM assets a, courseAssets ca, courses c, assetTags ast 
WHERE c.courseUser = {$userId} 
    AND c.id = ca.courseID 
    AND ca.assetID = a.id 
    AND ast.assetID = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
) temp
WHERE temp.counter < 5
```

Excuse any errors.  I also changed the assetTags alias "at" to "ast" just to avoid reserved words...